# Javascript - Adding a new column in an array using for loop - error

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm using an API to retrieve data on some stocks and I would like to add a column named symbol with the query values using the functon `insertColumn` but I'm getting an error `(node:15732) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined`.
I've tried changing `let result` to `this.result` and then do `insertColumn.call(this)`, but the same error occurs. I thought it would be related with a closure error, but at this point I'm not sure

```
import ObjectsToCsv from 'objects-to-csv';
import yahooFinance from 'yahoo-finance2';



async function api(){

  const query = 'TSLA';
  const queryOptions = { period1: '2021-08-06', interval: "1d"};
  let result = await yahooFinance.historical(query, queryOptions);

    function insertColumn() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.result.length; i++) {
        this.result[i].push({symbol: query});
      }
    };
    insertColumn();

  console.log(result);

  (async () => {
    const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(result);
    await csv.toDisk('C:/Users/Rafael Oliveira/Desktop/teste/test.csv');
  })();
};
api();
```

The output goes something like this:

```
[
  {
    date: 2021-08-06T00:00:00.000Z,
    open: 711.900024,
    high: 716.330017,
    low: 697.630005,
    close: 699.099976,
    adjClose: 699.099976,
    volume: 15576200
  },...
```

and I want it to be this:

```
[
  {
    date: 2021-08-06T00:00:00.000Z,
    open: 711.900024,
    high: 716.330017,
    low: 697.630005,
    close: 699.099976,
    adjClose: 699.099976,
    volume: 15576200
    symbol: 'TSLA' //this would be changed once I change the query part as well
  },
```

Comment: change ALL `this.result` to `result` .. and why is `insertColumn` a function, remove the function, keep the code inside it - similarly with your `(async () => {` ... remove that IIFE, kep its content - also, `result[i].push({symbol: query});` doesn't look right, since `result[i]` is an object not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably rather use javascript [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and append symbol to each item:

```js
import ObjectsToCsv from 'objects-to-csv';
import yahooFinance from 'yahoo-finance2';

async function api(){
  const query = 'TSLA';
  const queryOptions = { period1: '2021-08-06', interval: "1d" };
  const result = await yahooFinance.historical(query, queryOptions);
  const resultWithSymbol = result.map((item) => ({ ...item, symbol: query }));

  console.log(resultWithSymbol);

  (async () => {
    const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(resultWithSymbol);
    await csv.toDisk('C:/Users/Rafael Oliveira/Desktop/teste/test.csv');
  })();
};
api();
```

Comment: I'd love to know the reasoning behind the async IIFE inside an async function

Comment: Yes, that is unnecessary

Comment: Perhaps not, I can think of a reason it may be there - but not in this case, since nothing after the only await - i.e. you want to do some async/await that calling function doesn't need to wait for